# How can I use GraphRepositories to return complex POJO's with a specified depth (currently using Neo4j templating)

Tags: java, neo4j, mapping, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

**CONTEXT:**

I am working on a java spring web application backed by a Neo4j database. I have an object "Student" that has taken a number of "Modules" and "Courses". The relationship is connected via "rich relationship" nodes "RR_TakenModule" and "RR_TakenCourse" that specify a grade property.

```
public class Student extends DomainObject {
    String fullName;
    Gender gender;
    Collection<RR_TakenModule> modulesTaken;
    Collection<RR_TakenCourse> coursesTaken;
    DateTime yearStarted;
```

that way I could ask for a Student that got 74% in a Module

**PROBLEM:**

I cannot return a "deep" object, from the GraphRepository set up. Ie I cannot return a Student with populated "modulesTaken" and "coursesTaken" properties. I've seen several approaches online such as trying the cypher query :

```
MATCH (student:Student) -[:MODULES_TAKEN]-> (rr:RR_TakenModule) -[:MODULE]-> (m:Module) RETURN student, COLLECT(rr) as modulesTaken
```

Which is claimed to map the RR_TakenModules into the object dynamically via the property name. It does not do this for me and returns a "Error mapping GraphModel to instance of com.domain.Actors.Student" error code. Although note that it does properly group when running the cypher query in the localhost:7474 interface. Clearly mapping is the issue.

Currently I have adopted the template and Map approach. Using Neo4jOperations and the Result object. This works, however means that I have to write out iterators that go through and assign values based on the key/value pairs in the result object. This leads to high maintenance and a larger chance of errors.

Looking around their used to be options such as @Fetch, and specifying depth in Neo4jTemplate queries, however non of these methods seem to be present in my version (most appear to be depreciated)

**QUESTION :**

Is there a way to map sub-objects (ie "collection prop" and "set prop") of a Neo4j entity object via Graph Repositories. 
I realise there are predefined methods such as "findOne" that have a depth parameter, but I want to apply a similar implementation to my custom queries.

Alternatively, is there a solution for dynamically mapping a Neo4jOperations Result object to a java object without defining some custom json parser

**VERSIONS :**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-data-neo4j.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring-data-neo4j.version>
    <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Gosling-RELEASE</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: 4.1.1.RELEASE has better support for mapping entities from custom queries. Please upgrade to this release. More info here: http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/04/06/mapping-query-entities-sdn.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into the default "findOne(nodeid, depth)" method GraphRepositor offers I have found a solution that works for me.

I format the query as `MATCH (n:Entity) WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..4]->(m) RETURN p`
where Entity is the name of your base entity. I cannot justify why, but this format will dynamically map the result to your respective POJO.

Note you can specify the depth (*0..4) to specify how deep a POJO is populated. It is also worth noting that the relationship is using `-[]->` not  `-[]-` which is the default relationship for findOne(nodeid, depth). If this does not work it might be possible that you have not got the latest Neo4j OGM version.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data Neo4j (SDN) does not populate the referenced (by relationship) nodes in the returned node. It will, however populate the `fullName` and `gender` properties (assuming here that `Gender` is an `Enum` such that a string can be easily mapped).

In your query above you return a `Student` node and a collection of `RR_TakenModule`, but Spring does not know how to map this since there's no class that comprises these two results. You need to define an explicit result for this case. I suggest the following:

```
@NodeEntity(label = "Student")
public class Student extends DomainObject {
    @Property(name = "studentId")
    private String studentId; //you want to have this
    @Property(name = "fullName")
    private String fullName;
    @Property(name = "gender")
    private Gender gender; //assuming its an Enum
    @Relationship(type = "MODULES_TAKEN") // Relationship.OUTGOING is default
    private Set<RR_TakenModule) modulesTaken;
}
```

Then define a repository

```
public interface StudentRepository extends GraphRepository<Student> {

    @Query("MATCH (s:Student {studentId:{studentId}})-[:MODULES_TAKEN]->(m:RR_TakenModule) RETURN s AS student, collect(DISTINCT m) AS modulesTaken")
    public StudentWithModulesTakenResult getByUserIdWithModulesTaken(@Param("studentId") String studentId)
}
```

and the respective result

```
@QueryResult
public class StudentWithModulesTakenResult {
    private Student student;
    private Set<RR_TakenModule> modulesTaken;
    //only getters, no setters
}
```